# Get html body from response in groovy

Tags: html, groovy

I'm trying to see if a specific string exists in an html page but I can't seem to find an easy way to get the string that represents the body.

I've attempted:

```
http.request(Method.GET, { req ->
        uri.path = '/x/app/main'
        response.success = { resp, reader ->
            assert resp.status == 200
            println reader.text.startsWith('denied')
        }

        response.failure = { resp ->
            fail("Failure reported: ${resp.statusLine}")
        }
    })
```

but reader.text is a NodeChildren object.

How do I get the html (or more specifically, the contexts of the body) as a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an input stream directly off of the response.  Try this:

```
http.request(Method.GET, { req ->
    uri.path = '/x/app/main'
    response.success = { resp ->
        assert resp.status == 200
        println resp.entity.content.text.startsWith('denied')
    }

    response.failure = { resp ->
        fail("Failure reported: ${resp.statusLine}")
    }
})
```

Comment: Tried it and got the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
 at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.getContent(BasicHttpEntity.java:84)
 at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:87)

Comment: Make sure you're using a one-arg `response.success` closure.  If you use a two-arg version (`response.success = { resp, reader ->`), you'll get that exception.

Comment: That appears to have done it! Thanks.  Question: Is there any good docs that list what is in the response? I can't even find how you came up with that :)

Comment: Once you know what classes you're dealing with, the javadocs are not too bad.  In particular, [HttpResponseDecorator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HttpResponseDecorator.html) is a good starting point.